# Solve Integral equation with fsolve in Matlab

Tags: integration, matlab

I'm trying to solve the following double integral equation with Matlab:

$$A(x)=\int_0^x \mathrm du\int_u^1\cos(B(v))\mathrm dv $$

where A is a set of discrete values, known between $0$ and $1$ ($x$ values) with the boundary condition $A(0)=0,B(0)=-\pi/2.$
Solving this equation corresponds to determine the values of $B$ for $x$-values between $0$ and $1$.
I'm not sure what is the best way to solve this equation: using fsolve, iterative procedure or with a symbolic approach to find $B$, but the double integral seems difficult to calculate.

I greatly appreciate your help or advices to solve this equation.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. For which value of $ x $ the equality holds? Could you share the values of the function $ A $ and the $ B $ in a csv file?

Comment: For example, x values are defined by : x=0:0.01:1, and A(x) can be defined by the following function: A=-0.0001.*exp(-150.*(x-0.25).^2). Now, the question is how to get the values of B for the x-values ?

Comment: What is $ B $? Can you define its function as well.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I don't know the B function (just its value for x=0), it's the result of this double integral equation... that I'm looking for.